# Accessing image texture connected to Cycles material Diffuse BSDF

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

[image: Example]

Hey guys, I'm writing an blender python exporter and want to be able to export supported cycles material configurations.

Starting simple - diffuse with an image texture input:

```
diffuse_BSDF = mtl.node_tree.nodes['Diffuse BSDF']

if diffuse_BSDF != None:
   input = diffuse_BSDF.inputs[0]
```

... then not sure how to access the image texture from input which is a NodeSocketColor.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to zeffii :

```
    diffuse_BSDF = mtl.node_tree.nodes.get('Diffuse BSDF')

    if diffuse_BSDF != None:
        # grab color input
        input = diffuse_BSDF.inputs[0]

        if input.is_linked:
            src = input.links[0].from_node
            if src.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                self.File.Write('tex_src:{}\n'.format(src.image.filepath))
            elif src.type == 'MIX_RGB':
                for i in src.inputs:
                    if i.type == 'RGBA':
                        if i.is_linked:
                            src_i = i.links[0].from_node
                            if src_i.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                                self.File.Write('tex_src:{}\n'.format(src_i.image.filepath))
```

(obviously the write function is script specific but maybe that's helpful to others)